# How to integrate react-native app as a module in existing android app?

Tags: android, typescript, react-native

I have made a demo react-native app using typescript, and want to open that on a button click inside my native android project using an intent.. Can anyone provide a solution that actually works?

Comment: i think you can use it via WebView.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Two options. You need to have all the RN-dependencies in your project, so it might be easier to add your native project to the RN-project. Otherwise you can also add all the dependencies and build rules to your native project.

Then you might rename your RN-MainActivity to something like `MyReactActivity` and add that to your AndroidManifest.xml

In your native Activity you can then just call

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, MyReactActivity.class);
startActivity(intent);
```